# DynamoDB local db limits - use for initial beta-go-live

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamo-local

given Dynamo's pricing, the thought came to mind to use DynamoDB Local DB on an EC2 instance for the go-live of our startup SaaS solution.   I've been trying to find like a data sheet for the local db, specifying limits as to # of tables, or records, or general size of the db file.   Possibly, we could even run a few local db instances on dedicated EC2 servers as we know at login what user needs to be connected to what db.

Does anybody have any information on the local db limits or on this approach?  Also, anybody knows of any legal/licensing issues with using dynamo-local in that way?

Answer (score 0):

Every item in DynamoDB Local will end up as a row in the SQLite database file. So the limits are based on [SQLite's limitations](http://sqlite.org/limits.html).

Maximum Number Of Rows In A Table = 2^64 but the database file limit will likely be reached first (140 terabytes).

Note: because of the above, the number of items you can store in DynamoDB Local will be smaller with the preview version of local with Streams support. This is because to support Streams the update records for items are also stored. E.g. if you are only doing inserts of these items then the item will effectively be stored twice: once in a table containing item data and once in a table containing the INSERT UpdateRecord data for that item (more records will also be generated if the item is being updated over time).

Be aware that DynamoDB Local was not designed for the same performance, availability, and durability as the production service.

Comment: Excellent, thank you!  Is there an option to disable Streams support ?   Also, is it true then that in order to provide Dynamo-local, AWS emulated DynamoDB behavior using SQLite, i.e. is the AWS DynamoDB service also based on SQLite ?

Comment: Anyone faced this  error? I got this error when I trying create more than 9 global indexes in dynamodb local version via node js. ValidationException: No more than 20 attributes per table can be projected into Local Secondary Indices
?